# When is rng.gen() not true?

Tags: rust

I am using the number generator  from [std:rand](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/index.html) as a template for a generic random number generator. The problem is sometimes, the function was silently failing so I added a fail clause that simply prints "Not true!"

```
use std::rand;
use std::rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = rand::task_rng();
    if rng.gen() { // bool
        println!("f64: {}", rng.gen::<f64>());
    } else {
        println!("Not true!");
    }
}
```

Sometimes running the executable prints a random number and sometimes it prints "Not true!". What could possibly be causing rng.gen() to evaluate to false?

Edit:grammar

Comment: It would be cool if someone were to submit a pull request replacing the `bool` comment with e.g. `random bool`, or otherwise making this example clearer: [relevant code](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/b1302f9c4f6619bf83fff39b305b990d8f628eb7/src/libstd/rand/mod.rs#L58-L66).

Comment: Great call. PR made https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/14816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s look at the signatures.

[`fn gen<T: Rand>(&mut self) -> T`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/struct.TaskRng.html#tymethod.gen)

And [`Rand`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/trait.Rand.html)? “A type that can be randomly generated using an Rng.”, which includes among its implementors `bool`.

In simple terms, `gen()` can return a value of any type that implements `Rand`, based on the types that it can infer. You can get a random number, a random char, even a random bool.

An `if` clause must be of type bool. Therefore the type inferrer determines that the `T` for that particular `gen()` invocation is `bool`. You could also write `rng.gen::<bool>()` to the same effect.

Thus, which branch of your if/else structure will be evaluated is random.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of the Rng::gen](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/trait.Rng.html#tymethod.gen) method:

```
// Return a random value of a Rand type.
fn gen<T: Rand>(&mut self) -> T
```

When `T` is of type `bool`, then it will randomly generate either `true` or `false`. If it always generated a `true` value, it wouldn't be usefully random.

Generally, `if rng.gen() { ... } else { ... }` is a useful idiom to say, "Randomly choose one of two code paths."

Comment: Oh, so theres a random generator that returns a bool and within that true path, a random number generator. Thats an inception type first example. Thanks